# How do I use NLog with IronPython interpreter?

Tags: c#, ironpython, nlog

I have some assemblies written in C#, which I want to use with IronPython interpreter. These assemblies use NLog for logging, and if I use them from C# code, I can provide NLog settings with the NLog.config. But how can I configure logging if I use ipy.exe interpreter?

Comment: Possibly using the configuration API http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_API

Answer (score 0):

Put `nlog.config` next to the `ipy.exe`.